# python serial [Errno 13] Permission denied: /dev/tty*

Tags: linux, python-3.x, serial-port, linux-mint

I try to open serial port, but cant with permission.
But works with sudo.

How i can get permission for serial port?

```
sas@sas-linuxmint ~ $groups sas
sas : sas adm tty dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

This my code:

```
def get_serial_port():
    ser_devs = [dev for dev in os.listdir('/dev') if dev.startswith('tty')]
    for i in ser_devs:
        port = "/dev/" + i
        try :
            ser = serial.Serial(port, 19200)
            if ser.is_open:
                print("OPEN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! {}".format(port))
            ser.close()
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            print(e, port)
    return None
```

output:

```
[Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyprintk: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyprintk' /dev/ttyprintk
```

for all ports.

I tried change mod for port, but it doesn't work too

```
sudo chmod 766 /dev/ttyS10
sudo chmod -R a+rw /dev/ttyS10
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyS10
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS10
```

Comment: It look like it is not python issue. Did you try to use root or sudo to execute your code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this??  Not every tty is supposed to be handled by normal users, especially `/dev/ttyprintk` ;-)

Comment: "Did you try to use root or sudo to execute your code?" Yes, with sudo it works.

Comment: " Not every tty is supposed to be handled by normal users, especially /dev/ttyprintk ;-)" I try for all ports /dev/tty*, /dev/ttyprintk just first from list :)

Answer (score 0):

may be 2 years late but, you simply add your user to the tty group
eg:

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty $USER
```

[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210177/serial-port-terminal-cannot-open-dev-ttys0-permission-denied)

Comment: Output of the command `groups sas` already had that group, so this suggestion doesn't seem to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the following command:

```
sudo gpasswd --add ${USER} dialout
```

To add dialout to my group but with no luck. The following worked for me: (assuming tty1 is the name)

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/tty1
```